# Redirect my main GitHub page to another repository of mine

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Currently my page on GitHub is something like:

```
https://my_user.github.io
```

I have a repository with this URL published, and it can be accessed from anywhere.

```
https://my_user.github.io/cv/#!/home
```

I would like that when any person access to my personal GitHub URL, it will be redirected to my repository. When I access https://my_user.github.io , I must be redirected to https://my_user.github.io/cv/#!/home

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root namespace `https://my_user.github.io` is shown from `https://github.com/my_user/my_user.github.io` repository. You can put there an `index.html` with HTML redirect:

```
<meta HTTP-Equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://my_user.github.io/cv/#!/home">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I use the source tree program, how can I clone or add an index.html file in the address  `https://github.com/my_user/my_user.github.io`?

Comment: Create a new local repository; create `index.html`; add and commit. Login to Github in browser; create a new repository `my_user.github.io`. In your local repo add the new repo at github as `origin` (`git remote add origin https://github.com/my_user/my_user.github.io`). Push local repo to the remote (`git push -u origin master`). Wait a few minutes until Github updates Pages — for the first push it usually takes 10-15 minutes.